# Measuring statistical significance in online polling

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, inference, polling

I have online polling results with 1200 responses. 600 of the respondents were exposed to one set of images and the other 600 were exposed to another set of images. The respondents were then asked a series of questions which gauged their support for a particular political issue. The demographics of each individual were also recorded.

As I delve into these polling results, what would be the best way to measure:

1. That the two sets of respondents have a reasonably similar distribution of respondents given demographic information such as gender, age, race, income level, etc.
2. That the differences between the responses are statistically significant
3. The level of confidence that we have that the differences are within a particular range

For example, say that the respondents are asked if they support, are neutral towards, or are against issue A after seeing image X or image Y. For the 600 that see image X, 180 support issue A, 250 are neutral, and 170 oppose issue A. For the 600 that see image Y, 165 support issue A, 260 are neutral, and 175 oppose issue A. The group that saw image X has a demographic make-up of 330 women and 270 men; 250 lower class, 200 middle class, 150 upper class; 100 under 25 yrs, 350 25-45 yrs, and 150 over 45 yrs. The group that saw image Y has a demographic make-up of 325 women and 275 men; 260 lower class, 205 middle class, 145 upper class; 105 under 25 yrs, 340 25-45 yrs, and 155 over 45 yrs.

Given the above example, how can we measure the 3 metrics given above? Suppose even that we have the details of each individual person's demographic information and responses. Would it be safe to say that the populations are close enough demographically, supposing that the racial and other make-up is about as similar, to be able to conclude that image Y decreases support for issue A by over 8% (165/180 = 9.16667) as opposed to image X? Is this difference something that is likely to happen by random chance? How can we figure out how confident we are that the decrease in support should be between 4% and 12% (8% +/- 4%)? What about the sample size? How does the sample size play into the picture of accuracy?

Basically, I'd like to know how to approach a problem of this nature and how to present key findings in a rigorous way. Please let me know any specific tests that I can use, additional information that I might need to make more concrete conclusions, ways to avoid needing a mean or standard deviation (or ways to approximate those values if completely necessary), and any additional pieces of statistical detail that could be measured to enhance my study.